# How to set fixed Z scale in python visvis package?

Tags: python, 3d, surface

**assign clim to mesh fixed my problem!**

Need help for how to set a fixed z scale in visvis 3d surface.
I'm trying to use visvis to display a 3d surface , but I don't know how to change the Z  to fixed scale, for example, I'd like to show colorbar for (0,500),

```
import visvis

#xig,yig,zig for 3d surface
app=visvis.use()
f = visvis.gca()
m = visvis.surf(xig,yig,zi)
m.colormap = visvis.CM_JET
m.clim = 0, 500
visvis.colorbar()
f.axis.visible = True#False
app.Run()
```

[image: a 3d surface like below]

f.SetLimits(rangeX=[-150,150],rangeY=[-150,150],rangeZ=[0,500] doesn't work but set camera view only:

[image: jj]

modified version:

```
#use fixed z scale also color map scale
fixed_z_scale=500
z_scale=np.max(Z)-np.min(Z)
daspec_z=z_scale/fixed_z_scale

# visvis 
app=visvis.use()
app.Create()

f = visvis.gca()
f.daspect=1, 1, daspec_z
f.axis.visible = False
#mesh
m = visvis.surf(xig,yig,zi)
m.clim=200,700
m.colormap = visvis.CM_JET 

#view parameters
visvis.view({'zoom': 0.0035, 'elevation': 45.0})
visvis.title("Removal Thickness nm",axes=f)
visvis.colorbar()
#print(visvis.view())

#export image and mesh
visvis.processEvents()
visvis.screenshot("surf.jpg", sf=1)
visvis.meshWrite("surf.obj", m, "surf")

#if doesn't need GUI for users
#visvis.closeAll()

#show GUI window
app.Run()
```

[image: 3d surf]

Comment: i don't know for visvis but in matplotlib you could try `f.clim(0,500)`

Comment: thanks bobrobbob, yes, I tested matplotlib too,surf = ax.plot_surface(xig, yig, zig, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, vmin=0.0, vmax=0.5),
 how ever matplotlib refresh the image is not good enough when I rotate the surface.

Comment: i'm saying that you can try that matplotlib function in visvis. they share the same syntax it should be fine

Comment: thanks bobrobbob, unfortunately, no successful, when I add  f.clim(0,500) , I got  AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'clim'

Comment: sorry i got confused. it was `visvis.clim(0,500)`

Comment: thanks bobrobbob, finally I got it worked, should assign clim to mesh, m.clim=0,500.